# highcharts display tooltip on category label hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In Highcharts how do i get access to the click event on the category labels?

Im looking to add a tooltip to each label but struggling to find a way

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on each SVG label element and add click event by "on" function.

```
 $.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks,function(i,tick){
            tick.label.on('click',function(){
               alert(tick.pos);
            });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aPg8H/

Answer (score 0):

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782758/highcharts-adding-hyperlinks-to-the-x-axis-of-the-chart). But you would use the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter). The API has an example available as well [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/).

Comment: ok great thanks, how would i add an onclick event to it though and pass the this.value to a function