# Unbind the Click Action on xAxis Labels In Drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I remove the ability for the end user to click on the xAxis labels in a drilldown chart?
I do not see any lable `events` to hook into in the API. I have tried to modify the labels on load using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758465/how-to-handle-mouse-events-on-axis-labels-in-highcharts) answer:

```
var xAxis = this.xAxis[0];
var onXaxisRedraw = function () {
    for (var tickPos in xAxis.ticks) {
        var $element = $(xAxis.ticks[tickPos].label.element);
        $element.unbind('click');

    }
}
```

This is still letting the drilldown click action occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not aware of any way of doing this within the API I'll make a suggestion to remove it manually.

First step is to make the labels look like normal labels. This setup should achieve that:

```
drilldown: {
    activeAxisLabelStyle: {
        cursor: 'default',
        color: '#3E576F',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        textDecoration: 'none'
    }
}
```

Then remove the onclick events from the relevant labels when loaded and redrawing:

```
function removeClick() {
    $('.highcharts-drilldown-axis-label').each(function() {
        this.onclick = null;
    });
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                removeClick();
            },
            redraw: function() {
                removeClick();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

And [a JSFiddle drilldown chart](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu4Nb/) to see it in action.

Comment: Excellent. This did the trick. I am not modding the text except removing the click-pointer cursor.